# How to submit form without refresh, show output, reload form, rinse and repeat

Tags: php, javascript, ajax, forms, partial-page-refresh

I have a form that has drop down list options, an input box and a submit button.  The select options are dynamically compiled.  I place this form on my page by inserting;

```
<div id="dropdown">
       <?php include("./listforward.php"); ?>
</div>
```

listforward.php contains;

```
...
<form id="changeforwardForm" method="post" action="changeforward.php" class="ajaxform">
...
</form>
```

changeforward.php does some work and gives a message;

```
<?php echo '<div style="color:red">'.$msg.'</div>'; ?>
```

After submit, this message is displayed near the top of the page

```
<div id="testDiv"></div>
```

and, the entire form is reloaded to show updated list options.  The problem I have is that the message shows only once at the top from the first submission, and on the second submission it opens a blank page and shows it there.

I am aware that this has something to do with .live() or .on() but for the life of me I can not figure out how to apply it.

My external Javascript files

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.7.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="jquery.form.js"></script>
```

[jQuery Form Plugin](http://jquery.malsup.com/form/#ajaxForm)

```
<script type="text/javascript"> 
  // prepare the form when the DOM is ready 
  $(document).ready(function(){ 
      var options = { 
          target:        '#testDiv',   // target element(s) to be updated with server response 
          success:       showResponse  // post-submit callback 
  }; 

  // bind form using 'ajaxForm' 

  $('.ajaxform').ajaxForm(options);          

  });         


  // post-submit callback 
  function showResponse(responseText, statusText, xhr, $form)  { 

     $("#dropdown").load("index.php #dropdown");

       }  
</script>
```

I also have another form on the same page (currently disabled).  I would like to target the output of this form and have it display its message at #testDiv.

Any kick in the right direction would be much appreciated!

Regards Steven

Answer (score 0):

you havn't shown all the code, but from what i can understand you use:

```
$('.ajaxform').ajaxForm(options);          

  });
```

to attach your function to the from submit.
Then as you said you reload the form so the function is not attached any more.
then when you resubmit it behaves like a regular submit.

you should reattach your method to the form after it is reloaded, i.e. run this again:

```
$('.ajaxform').ajaxForm(options);          

      });
```

Comment: Hi Daniel, I have posted all the code that is applicable.  You are absolutely right, the function is detached, unfortunately I've already tried your method and it doesn't do the trick.

Comment: you could post the whole html code as it gets to the browser. in this case i suspect the php source is not of much use as the problem - as you state it - involves html/javascript and has nothing to do with the php script.